# A/An articles in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Is there something like [#pluralize in ActiveSupport][1] but for `a`/`an` articles?

So basically I need something like:

```ruby
'status'.articleize # => "a status"
'urgent'.articleize # => "an urgent"
```

Comment: Add this to your test cases: "He was a one-eyed seaman who considered it an honor to serve on the pirate ship".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `String#articleize` to return the appropriate [English article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles):

```
class String
  def articleize
    if self[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i
      "an #{self}"
    else
      "a #{self}"
    end
  end
end

'status'.articleize # => "a status"
'urgent'.articleize # => "an urgent"
```

Comment: I obviously didn't use the right search terms when I looked for a previous answer as this has now been flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the [Linguistics gem](https://deveiate.org/code/linguistics/README_rdoc.html) might be up for the job. Let's try Cary Swoveland's challenge:

```
require 'linguistics/en'
Linguistics.use(:en)

"one-eyed seaman".en.a
=> "a one-eyed seaman"
"honor".en.a
=> "an honor"

# And OP examples...
"urgent update".en.a
=> "an urgent update"
"status update".en.a
=> "a status update"
```